# After packaging my python code, print statements in included files aren't showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-packaging

So after I packaged my python program to one big package, only print statements in my `main.py` file are executed.

This is bad because I can't debug my code this way.

My `setup.py` file that installs the module defines a function called `launch` in `main.py` as an [entrypoiny](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#entry-points).
I would like to be able to write print statements into any file that `main.py` includes (all written by me) to print anything I've written to those files.

My project structure is some what similar to this:

```
Folder
    setup.py
    package_name
        __init__.py (empty)
        main.py -> print statements added here DO print
        utility
            __init__.py (empty)
            util.py -> print statements added here don't print
```

Comment: Is `package_name.utility.util` getting imported?

Comment: Yes, main.py uses a function from package_name.utility.util

Comment: Your `setup.py` should not execute code that you are trying to package. Code that is used to build the package and code that is shipped are two completely distinct things, and trying to treat them as the same is an issue in general, but might also be the reason things are not working out for you right now. Can you maybe show us your `setup.py` as well? And maybe also the part where `main.py` imports and calls `util`?

Comment: https://github.com/CountryTk/PyPad/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Hmm, I think the main problem about your package is that you're using print statements instead of a logger. I can't test it and write an answer right now though.

Comment: Wait, [you're defining a logger](https://github.com/CountryTk/PyPad/blob/master/pypad/utils/config.py#L8). Why are you not using it?